# No endpoint mapping found when setting up Spring Web Service

Tags: web-services, spring, spring-ws, endpoint

I'm a beginner at setting up spring web-applications. I got this far but now I find myself stuck.

I get the following error:

```
WARNING: No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {http://mycompany.com/weather/schemas}GetCities]
```

The main problem is that I have run out of ideas where to look for debug information. I fixed as many errors that I've seen, but now I can't even find something wrong in the logs. So I'm getting bit desperate.

This my web.xml

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>Weather report webservice</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/weatherws</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is what my spring-ws-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="path.to.weather"/>

    <sws:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

This is what my endpoint looks like:

```
@Endpoint
public class WeatherEndpoint {

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://mycompany.com/weather/schema";

    private WeatherReportManager manager;

    @Autowired
    public WeatherEndpoint(WeatherReportManager manager) throws JDOMException {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "GetCities")
    @ResponsePayload
    public Element getCities() {
        Element toReturn = null;

        for(City city : manager.getCities()) {
            //To some stuff
        }

        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

This is the catalina.log as I see it right now. I tried to get Tomcat to output DEBUG messages by editing the logging.properties. This did not give any additional effect.

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive weather.war
Feb 15, 2012 3:28:51 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring-ws': initialization started
Feb 15, 2012 3:28:51 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-ws-servlet': startup date [Wed Feb 15 15:28:51 EET 2012]; root of context hierarchy
Feb 15, 2012 3:28:52 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml]
Feb 15, 2012 3:28:52 PM org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AbstractAddressingEndpointMapping afterPropertiesSet
INFO: Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
Feb 15, 2012 3:28:52 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@36496381: defining beans [weatherEndpoint,weatherReportManagerWWW,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping#0,org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.mapping.SoapActionAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping#0,org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping#0,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.dom.DomPayloadMethodProcessor#0,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.SourcePayloadMethodProcessor#0,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.XmlRootElementPayloadMethodProcessor#0,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.JaxbElementPayloadMethodProcessor#0,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.dom.JDomPayloadMethodProcessor#0,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
Feb 15, 2012 3:28:52 PM org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory afterPropertiesSet
INFO: Creating SAAJ 1.3 MessageFactory with SOAP 1.1 Protocol
Feb 15, 2012 3:28:52 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring-ws': initialization completed in 714 ms
Feb 15, 2012 3:28:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
Feb 15, 2012 3:28:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
Feb 15, 2012 3:28:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory host-manager
Feb 15, 2012 3:28:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory lib
Feb 15, 2012 3:28:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory manager
Feb 15, 2012 3:28:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
Feb 15, 2012 3:28:53 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Feb 15, 2012 3:28:53 PM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
Feb 15, 2012 3:28:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 8777 ms
Feb 15, 2012 3:29:07 PM org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher dispatch
WARNING: No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {http://mycompany.com/weather/schemas}GetCities]
```

I would be very grateful for any assistance. If you need to see anything additional, just let me know.

Comment: You're mapping your `MessageDispatcherServlet` to the base path of `weatherws`, yet all of your other endpoints suggest you want it to be `weather`.

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild correct me if I'm mistaken (just new at this). Using the soapUI I was using endpoint 'http://localhost:8080/weather/weatherws' since I deployed everything from 'weather.war'. Thereafter I mapped it just to 'weather'. Then I had to use the endpoint 'http://localhost:8080/weather/weather', but the latter had the same effect. As I see it the mapping doesn't seem to be the problem. Since it seems to find the servlet itself (had problem with initializing the servlet earlier).

Comment: I am not familiar with Spring-WS, it is just something that looked strange to me.  If you are sure that you are hitting the `MessageDispatcherServlet`, then please feel free to ignore my uninformed comment. :)

Comment: @Vampnik and Others .I had a question in your XSD'd Do u have element name with Getcities or GetitiesRequest ?
Because in my webservice(spring+soap) until and unless I'm making elements suffixed with Request in wsdl operation they are not loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your endpoint code you have :

```
private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://mycompany.com/weather/schema";
```

but your message is from `http://mycompany.com/weather/schemas` namespace. Note the final **s**.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That was the problem. I quess it's true what they say: "It's always the smallest things." I was starting to go nuts over obsessing over this.

Comment: @soulcheck should Request element in XSD be suffixed with Request. Is that a way to tell soap to that it is a request element?