# Springs ws no Endpoint mapping found for

Tags: java, web-services, soap, spring-ws, endpoint

So I was getting this error which trying to hit my Webservice

```
No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {http://www.example.org/Fta_Consumption/Interface/}triggerFTARequest
```

My Endpoint class looks like

```
@Endpoint
public class TriggerFtaEndPoint {
    private static final String NAMESPACE_URL = "http://www.example.org/Fta_Consumption/Interface/";

    @PayloadRoot(localPart = "triggerFTARequest", namespace = NAMESPACE_URL)
    @ResponsePayload@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public TriggerFTAResponse triggerFta(@RequestPayload TriggerFTARequest request, MessageContext messageContext) {
```

So before asking this question I tried going through the link

[No endpoint mapping found when setting up Spring Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294774/no-endpoint-mapping-found-when-setting-up-spring-web-service)

But still I am not able to figure out my issue. Everthing seems to be in place but still unable to figure out the issue.

Comment: Try without the trailing '/' after "...Interface/"

Comment: I got the issue. As per my current framework I had to declare the bean into springs-ws file. I thought simple by annotating with with `@Endpoint` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue. As per my current framework I had to declare the bean into `springs-ws` file. I thought simple by annotating with with `@Endpoint` will do the trick.

Comment: Could you rephrase that ? What is this `springs-ws` file ?